# unble to replace string

Tags: java

This is my replace method  in java but unble to replace for following.

It replace only one \

Please help. If any body have any different method for replace?

I had tried java standard API but that is not working can please try following senario
--> System.out.println(replace("this%s is the problem" , "%" , "\%"));

```
public static String replace(String str, String sub, String rep) {
        int s, p, q;
        int slen = sub.length();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        s = 0;
        p = str.indexOf(sub);
        q = p + slen;
        while (p != -1) {
            sb.append(str.substring(s, p));
            sb.append(rep);
            s = q;
            p = str.indexOf(sub, s);
            if (p != -1) {
                q = p + slen;
            }
        }
        sb.append(str.substring(s));
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use replaceAll? http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: replaceAll is a regex-method which may lead to some confusions

Comment: what is the expected outcome btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the replaceAll method.  You just need to be careful escaping the \ and % (although I don't fully understand why you need four '\'s)!

```
String myString = "this%s is the problem";
myString = myString.replaceAll("%","\\\\%);
```

Comment: You'd better (re)assign what `myString.replace(...)` returns.

Comment: I don't want four time , i want 2 times \, but replace is generated only one \

Comment: Java will understand "\\" as the standard character "\" (from the java.util.regex.Pattern class used in the regex). Thus the four "\" are understood as two "\" :)

Answer (score 1):

Escaping escape signs is a bit tedious in Java, but this should do what you want (if you want `\\%`):

```
System.out.println("this%s is the problem".replace("%" , "\\\\%"));
```

If you want `\%` it's this:

```
System.out.println("this%s is the problem".replace("%" , "\\%"));
```

Also note that this won't work properly with `replaceAll`, which takes regexes, other than `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a replaceAll() method

Comment: System.out.println("this%s is the problem".replaceAll("%" , "\\%"));

Replace all is not working

Comment: replaceAll is a regex-method which may lead to some confusions

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#replace(String, String, String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)